# Batch Class CallOutLimit Doubt

Tags: batch, governorlimits

As we have 10 callout governor Limit in each execution . 
So I can query 100 records in start and execute the batch class with batch size as 1 and do 10 callout for each record . So total I can query 100*10 . Plus 10 callouts of start method and 10 for finish .

Is this possible ?

Comment: I tried this and it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

The:

> Total number of callouts (HTTP requests or Web services calls) in a
>   transaction

governor limit is 10 and each `execute` call made by the Batchable mechanism is a separate transaction.

The maximum number of records that can be returned from the `start` method of a [Batchable](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_batch_interface.htm) providing a QueryLocator is used is 50,000,000.

So you can tune the batch size to stay within the callout limit in each execute and you can in theory process up to 50,000,000 records...

Comment: Have you practically tried this? I doubt that you can call more than 10 callouts in batch context.

Comment: @AtulRajguru9 Agreed. I'm saying if its 1 callout per record the batch size could be set to 10 but if its 10 callouts per record the batch size would have to be set to 1. The question was phrased a little confusingly and 10 callouts per record is a pretty extreme requirement so I didn't want to repeat that in the answer.

Answer (score -1):

you can use more than 10 callout in batch

Comment: Would you please elaborate and provide a reference to the Apex documentation to support your answer, thus providing a more complete answer? Thank you.